# Deserialize JSON Response from Rest Query, ERROR: System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: json, rest

Trying to convert some JSON to an Account List, I suspect my error is because the query next stuff coming into the response. How can I convert these results to an account list?

```
HttpRequest feedRequest = new HttpRequest();
feedRequest.setEndpoint('callout:sandwich/services/data/v46.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account');
feedRequest.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse feedResponse = http.send(feedRequest);

String s = feedresponse.getBody();
List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(s, List<Account>.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [response body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) from the sObject Query endpoint is not a record list. Here's the example response body from the linked documentation:

```
{
    "done" : true,
    "totalSize" : 14,
    "records" : 
    [ 
        {  
            "attributes" : 
            {    
                "type" : "Account",    
                "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/001D000000IRFmaIAH"  
            },  
            "Name" : "Test 1"
        }, 
        {  
            "attributes" : 
            {    
                "type" : "Account",    
                "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/001D000000IomazIAB"  
            },  
            "Name" : "Test 2"
        }, 

        ...

    ]
}
```

It's actually a dictionary, with a nested sObject list. If you want to use strongly-typed deserialization, you'll have to define an outer wrapper object to represent that top-level dictionary, something like

```
class Response {
    public Boolean done;
    public Integer totalSize;
    public List<Account> records;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I still am having trouble with how to get my results into the Account List, can you show an example strongly-typed deserialization line if you can

Comment: @AllabouttheW You already have most of the code you need. You just need to deserialize into a class like `Response` above, rather than a `List<Account>`.

Comment: I think I am close, sorry to be needed. Where I am confused is response class is not a list, but a object with a list inside of it. So I need to make it work like this? List<Account> accounts = (Response) JSON.deserialize(s, Response.List<Accounts>.class);

Comment: @AllabouttheW You need to declare a variable of type `Response`. Then, you need to call `JSON.deserialize()` with the second parameter `Response.class`. Finally, you can access your Accounts via the `records` property of the returned `Response`.

Answer (score 3):

You can see what the return looks like in workbench. It's not returning a list of Accounts which is why you're not able to deserialize the way you're attempting. You can create a custom class (AccountQueryWrapper) to deserialize the response

`public class AccountQueryWrapper {
     public Integer totalSize;
     public boolean done;
     public List records;
}`

The records will contain your account Ids.

[image]

[image]